# Why are the colors changing on my graph when I remove the grid lines?

Tags: r, r-dygraphs

I have the following graph:

```
library(dygraphs)


set.seed(1)
date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-01"), by = "month")
var1 <- rnorm(length(date), mean = 100, sd = 10)
var2 <- rnorm(length(date), mean = 50, sd = 5)
df <- data.frame(date, var1, var2)

library(xts)
df_xts <- xts(df[,-1], order.by = df$date)

dygraph(df_xts, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
    dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
    dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
    dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
    dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

When I remove the grid lines, the colors seem to change:

```
dygraph(df_xts, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
    dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
    dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
    dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
    dyRangeSelector(height = 20) %>%
    dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE, drawGrid = FALSE)
```

[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this (i.e. make the colors in the second graph appear more similar to the first graph)?

**Note:** Here is the answer that worked for me based on @user20650's comment:

```
dygraph(df_xts, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
    dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
    dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
    dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE, drawGrid = FALSE)
```

Comment: Try it with just one `dyOptions` call e.g. use `dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE, drawGrid = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of multiple `dyOptions` calls is likely causing some options to be over-written. **Soln:** just use one `dyOptions` call.

Example:

```
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)

# reproducible data
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix[, 1:2])

dygraph(sample.xts) |>
    dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE, drawGrid = FALSE) |>
    dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

Toggle the `drawGrid = FALSE` option to get the same plot with/without grid lines.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I tried to apply your logic to another question - if you have time, can you please take a look at it? thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041654/r-stacked-graph-produces-different-colors-than-non-stacked